# increasing the Framerate to this Processing Script

Tags: svg, processing, frame-rate, minim

I'm currently working on this script for a project I'm doing, and I'm not happy with the current frame rate. It's bouncing around FPS, and I need at least 30 so I can further use it in a video installation without lag.

Since my math is terrible, and I didn't quite understand how the original other did the math, I can't figure out where the redundant code is. 
I've been working on that for a whole day with no results.

Holler if you need the original .aif or the svg.

I think you can substitute with any kind of audio track, because as much as I can gather, these calculation are run separately.

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer data1;
AudioPlayer data2;
AudioPlayer data3;
AudioPlayer data4;

/* OpenProcessing Tweak of *@*http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/6598*@* */
/* !do not delete the line above, required for linking your tweak if you upload again */
float grid[][][];
PGraphics boundary;
int page = 0;
int sides = 3; 
float w = PI/10;
PShape world;

public void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080, FX2D);
  //fullScreen(FX2D, 0);
  frameRate(30);
  grid = new float[2][width-1][height-1];
  boundary = createGraphics(width, height);

  world = loadShape("world.svg");

  makeBoundary(sides);
  loadPixels();

  minim = new Minim (this);


  data1 = minim.loadFile ("indo.aif");
  data1.loop();
  data1.play();

  data2 = minim.loadFile ("chile.aif");
  data2.loop();
  data2.play();

  data3 = minim.loadFile ("fuku.aif");
  data3.loop();
  data3.play();

  data4 = minim.loadFile ("samoa.aif");
  data4.loop();
  data4.play();
}

void makeBoundary(int sides) {
  for (int i=0; i<width-1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<height-1; j++) {
      grid[page][i][j] = 0;
      grid[page^1][i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  boundary.beginDraw();
  boundary.background(0);
  boundary.fill(255);
  boundary.shape(world, 0, 0, 1860, 1020);


  boundary.endDraw();
}

public void draw() {
  println(frameRate);


  float thresh = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 255);
  oscillator(data1, 380, 700, 32); // Indonesian Wellenquelle
  oscillator(data2, 1470, 780, 32); 
  oscillator(data3, 570, 400, 32);
  oscillator(data4, 700, 750, 32);


  for (int i=1; i<width-2; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<height-2; j++) {
      int wa = boundary.pixels[i+width*j];
      float dx =  (wa == 0xffffffff) ? 0: (grid[page][i-1][j] + grid[page][i+1][j]);  
      float dy =  (wa == 0xffffffff) ? 0: (grid[page][i][j-1] + grid[page][i][j+1]);  
      float value = (dx+dy )/2 - grid[page^1][i][j] ;


      grid[page^1][i][j] = value * 0.992;

      int val = (int) (abs(value) * 512);
      val = val > 255 ? 255 : val;
      pixels[i+j*width] = 0xFF000000 | val << 16 | val << 8 | val;
    }
  }

  page ^= 1;
  updatePixels();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(380, 700, 64, 64);
  ellipse(1470, 780, 64, 64);
  ellipse( 570, 400, 64, 64);
  ellipse(700, 750, 64, 64);
}



public void oscillator(AudioPlayer data, int x, int y, int r) {

  //grid[page][cx][cy] = sou.mix.level() * 60; // Zahl ändert Anzahl von Kreisen/Wellen
  //w += PI/16;

  int r2 = r * r;
  int area = r2 << 2;
  int rr = r << 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < area; i++)
  {
    int tx = (i % rr) - r;
    int ty = (i / rr) - r;

    if (tx * tx + ty * ty <= r2)
      grid[page][x + tx][y + ty] = data.mix.level() * 30;
    //SetPixel(x + tx, y + ty, c);
  }
}

public void mousePressed() {
  makeBoundary(++sides);
}

public void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    sides = 3;
    makeBoundary(sides);
  }
  //saveFrame();
}
```

Comment: Right now your question is too broad for us to give you good answers. Have you tried narrowing it down at all? Which line is taking the most time?

Comment: Im assuming this equation here:
for (int i=1; i<width-2; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<height-2; j++) {
      int wa = boundary.pixels[i+width*j];
      float dx =  (wa == 0xffffffff) ? 0: (grid[page][i-1][j] + grid[page][i+1][j]);  
      float dy =  (wa == 0xffffffff) ? 0: (grid[page][i][j-1] + grid[page][i][j+1]);  
      float value = (dx+dy )/2 - grid[page^1][i][j] ;

Comment: Why are you assuming? Do some benchmarking. You can use the `millis()` function to time different parts of your program.